# How to fix "gcc isn't recognized as internal command" on Clion for Window?

Tags: c, gcc, clion

I followed the [Clion installation guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/clion-quick-start-guide.html?_ga=2.136033145.91950200.1572341040-2004664547.1569241828) and I installed [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/).

So now I coded a C program and I try to type in the terminal `gcc test.c`but I get `gcc isn't a recognized internal command`

Here is my program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct a_struct {int a; int b; int c;};

int main()
{

    struct a_struct* pa = (struct a_struct*) 1000;
    printf ("pa=%ld\n", (long)pa);

    struct a_struct* pb = &pa[10];
    printf ("pb=%ld\n", (long)pb);

    struct a_struct* pc = pa + 10;
    printf ("pc=%ld\n", (long)pc);

    struct a_struct* pd = pc--;
    printf ("pc=%ld, pd=%ld\n", (long)pc, (long)pd);

    struct a_struct* pe = ++pb;
    printf ("pe=%ld, pb=%ld\n", (long)pe, (long)pb);

    return 0;
}
```

And in Clion settings I have:

[image]

Comment: you probably need to add to PATH the path to gcc.exe (typically C:\MinGW\bin )

Comment: @nivpeled as system var or user var ?

Comment: either is ok...

Comment: thank you it works now, you can add an answer so I can upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall add to PATH environment variable (either user or system wide) the path to gcc.exe (which typically resides @ C:\MinGW\bin)